# AttributeError: module 'cv2.face' has no attribute 'LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()'

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, opencv3.0

Currently working on a project but I have encountered this error. I have already installed opencv-contrib-python, yet I encountered this problem

```
import cv2

recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
```

Is there a way to get around this problem?

I also tried uninstalling and installing opencv-contrib-python, yet im still stumped on what to do here.

Comment: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'face'. so this code will not work...

Comment: What  is OpenCV version and Python version?